# can't use read_csv with fields having comma between \"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have the following table:

```
\"Column,One\",Column Two, Column Three
```

I'm attempting to read it using Pandas `read_csv`

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(fin, header=None, quotechar='"', escapechar='\\', quoting=0)
```

My desired way to store the table is:

```
0             1              2 
Column,One    Column Two     Column Three
```

But currently, when I print the table I get:

```
0         1       2            3
"Column   One"    Column Two   Column Three
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output? Your command creates a dataframe but not an output, please clarify.

Comment: @xyzjayne I assume output = result of `print(dataset)`... ;-)

Comment: If "\"Column,One\",Column Two, Column Three" is how your data is represented in your CSV, then I'd recommend a swift kick to whoever is responsible for that.

Comment: Thanks coldspeed for the clarification, By "the output" I meant print(dataset.head()). And yes, Unfortunately the table is stored in the given format.

Comment: pretty sure this isn't "legal" CSV, as any delimiter instance not meant to be a delimiter must be escaped. Otherwise, there would be no unambiguous way to specify a dataset that actually looks like the undesired output. Your only real options are to make some kind of input sanitizer before feeding it into your CSV reader or to merge columns that would be be bounded on both ends by quotes like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['0'] = df[['0', '1']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x).translate(str.maketrans('','','"')), axis=1)
```

The only way out is to remove '"' after reading the data frame and followed by combining column 0 and column 1.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try escaping the comma instead? 
"Column \, One",Column Two, Column Three